# Use DLL in C without lib

Tags: c, dll

How can I use the functions in a DLL in C without a LIB file to go with it? I know all of the function prototypes and their names.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes you can. You should use the [GetProcAddress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/64tkc9y5%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) function, to call the function directly in the DLL, without involving the LIB

> Processes explicitly linking to a DLL call GetProcAddress to obtain
>   the address of an exported function in the DLL. You use the returned
>   function pointer to call the DLL function.

To quote the Example from the above link:

```
typedef UINT (CALLBACK* LPFNDLLFUNC1)(DWORD,UINT);
...

HINSTANCE hDLL;               // Handle to DLL
LPFNDLLFUNC1 lpfnDllFunc1;    // Function pointer
DWORD dwParam1;
UINT  uParam2, uReturnVal;

hDLL = LoadLibrary("MyDLL");
if (hDLL != NULL)
{
   lpfnDllFunc1 = (LPFNDLLFUNC1)GetProcAddress(hDLL,
                                           "DLLFunc1");
   if (!lpfnDllFunc1)
   {
      // handle the error
      FreeLibrary(hDLL);
      return SOME_ERROR_CODE;
   }
   else
   {
      // call the function
      uReturnVal = lpfnDllFunc1(dwParam1, uParam2);
   }
}
```

Comment: This is what I'm going to do. I'll tell you about my experience when this project is over. I'm trying to remote control an old legacy Winradio 3000 series card running in an old computer. My dad wants to be able to use it wherever he is and seems to think that remote controlling is magically going to be easy to do. Well, I've got music streaming from one computer to another right now so there's a start, now I only need to implement the controls with the DLL that comes with winradio and my dad's magical remote control will be finished.

Comment: Yes, this works very well! Nothing to it really. The documentation for the Winradio API was a bit confusing (DWORD in their world is unsigned long in my world apparently). Other than that this was very easy. Thanks very much!

Comment: What id you have the LIB file?

Answer (score 4):

You can use LoadLibrary() and GetProcAddress() as described in the answer by DarkXphenomenon.  Or, another alternative is to create your own import library for the DLL by creating a .def file then running that through the LIB command to generate an import library.  Additional details here:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/131313